# AWS codeBuild/codePipeline with serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to automate **Deployment Pipeline** for my application. Here is the automation architecture, I came up with:
[image: Automation Architecture]

As you can see, I am using **codePipeline** and **codeBuild** to automate my deployment. My backend is based on [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/), which deploys lambda functions on firing `sls deploy` command. This is the reason, I did not use **codeDeploy** to do traditional deployment. `buildspec.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      – apt-get -y update
      – npm install -g serverless@1.9.0
  build:
    commands:
      – cd nj2jp/serverless && npm install
  post_build:
    commands:
      – serverless deploy –verbose

artifacts:
  files:
    – serverless.yml
  discard-paths: yes
```

Now, I have **3 Questions** in regards to **CodeBuild** and **Serverless**:

**Question 1:** The command `sls deploy` depends on a file called `config.yml` which contains secrets such as db password. This file will not be checked into git. What do you think is the best possible way to include `config.yml` in codeBuild?

**Question 2:** **Rollbacks** can be done with AWS, if we have to deploy traditional EC2 applications using **codeDeploy**. In case of serverless, we are not using **codeDeploy** and serverless also supports **rollback** features. How do we leverage serverless rollback within the **codePipeline**?

**Question 3:** Triggering codePipeline when a **Pull Request** happens. I saw some posts saying, it is not supported by codePipeline. But those posts were from last year, Is Pull Request now supported by codePipeline?

**Hack Answers**(Not correct, but works. Need better answers from you.)

**Answer 1:** The `config.yml` file can be saved in a private **S3 bucket** and can be pulled to codeBuild as part of `pre-build` setup or We can add all secrets to codeBuild's Env variables. I dont like the second option, as I want to have  consistent across all environments. Any better solutions for this problem?

**Answer 2:** I cannot think of an hack for this. Looking out for answers from you.

**Answer 3:** I came across some blog posts that use [[APIGateway + Lambda + S3]](https://nicolai86.eu/blog/posts/2017-03-25/awesome-aws-codepipeline-ci/) to trigger **codePipeline** for pull requests. But I feel, this feature has to be provided as an out-of-box one. Is there any updates on the codePipeline for this feature?

Comment: What is the tool you used to create the above diagram?

Comment: @Vinujan.S cloudcraft

Comment: How did you add the profile to the serverless?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Question 1**

*Update:*

Serverless framework now supports referencing variables from the Parameter Store. That means you can skip defining them in CodeBuild as serverless will retrieve them from Parameter Store upon deploy.

Example:

*serverless.yaml*

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: us-west-2
  stage: ${env:REGION}
  environment:
    S3_BUCKET: ${env:/s3/bucket}
    # Use ~true for SecureString parameters
    DB_USERNAME: ${ssm:/db/username~true}
    DB_PASSWORD: ${env:/db/password~true}
```

---

*Original Answer:*

If you want to stick with your `config.yml`, then the only way to make it work is through hacks similar to what you are already doing since it is not version-controlled.

What I'd suggest is to have your environment variables stored in EC2 Parameter Store which you can reference in your CodeBuild `buildspec.yml`. These variables are accessible in your `serverless.yml` using `${env:VARIABLE_NAME}`.

For local development, you should also use real environment variables versus storing them in `config.yml`. Tools such as [direnv](https://direnv.net) are great at this.

**Question 2**

You can do manual rollbacks by re-running the previous CodeBuild job. I can't think of an easy way to do it automatically like what CodeDeploy does. Maybe a Lambda function can do a post-deploy test and if it fails, it can trigger re-running the previous CodeBuild job.

**Question 3**

CodePipelines are tied to a single branch so to make it work on PR branches, you have to do hacks like the article you mentioned. I have resorted to using *API Gateway* + *Lambda* + *CodeBuild* (No *CodePipeline*) to do this.

Comment: Wonderful Answer!! Your answer completely makes sense. Just curious, How do you manage the environments (secrets) across different branches(prod, dev & stg). I am using a explicit `.env` file for each environment like `.env.prod`, `.env.dev` and `.env.stg`. All these are not checked into the git.

Comment: My secrets are all stored in EC2 Parameter Store. My dev, staging, and production are using separate AWS accounts. So, I can easily use the same variable names without worrying about clashes.

Comment: Ah nice!! But how do you manage it in the local environment? Like it is going to be same variables but different values. Do you version-control the env file too? If yes, that makes sense. I think, It is good for private repos.

Comment: You should only need one set of variables in for local environment and it should be gitignored. If you need to switch to using staging or production variables from time-to-time, you can put them all in one file and just comment out the ones you don't need. I'm using `direnv`, and the `.envrc` are basically shell scripts so commenting out values is easy-peasy.

Comment: @Lakshman Diwaakar: I'm trying almost exactly the same thing as you.  Would appreciate it if you could post the buildspec.yml and serverless.yml you have.  I need to reference the process.env.DB_PASSWORD in my lambda code and can't work out the correct way of getting it from Parameter Store to code.  Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the accepted answer given for Question 1 (Thanks @dashmug and @Lakshman Diwaakar)

*This does sort out how to get the Parameter Store values into your Lambda.  However, the values are shown as plain text in the Lambda console.  I need to work out next is how to add encryption.*

**Parameter Store**

Add your env variables as parameters in *AWS Systems Manager > Parameter store*

https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/parameters

**buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2    
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install -g serverless
  build:
    commands:
      - serverless deploy
```

**serverless.yml**

Reference the created Params in serverless.yml

Append ~true for secure strings.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: eu-west-1
  stage: prod
  environment:
    FOO: ${ssm:/app/production/foo}
    DB_USERNAME: ${ssm:/app/production/myDatabase/username~true}
    DB_PASSWORD: ${ssm:/app/production/myDatabase/password~true}
```

**handler.js**

Use the env vars in your handler

```
export async function main (event, context, callback) {

  console.log('process.env.FOO', process.env.FOO)
  console.log('process.env.DB_USERNAME', process.env.DB_USERNAME)
  console.log('process.env.DB_PASSWORD', process.env.DB_PASSWORD)

  callback(null, ok('success'))
}
```